# Find an eigenvalue decomposition of a hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose A $ \in \mathbb C^{m\times m}$  has an $SVD:  A =  U\sum V^*$. Find an eigenvalue
decomposition form of the $2m \times 2m$ hermitian matrix 
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}
0&A^*
\\
A&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I cannot get the eigenvalue decomposition form of $ B=X\sum X^*$. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

We have 
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix}0&V\\U&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&\Sigma\\\Sigma^*&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&U^*\\V^*&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
and
$$
W\begin{pmatrix}0&\Sigma\\\Sigma^*&0\end{pmatrix}W^*=2\begin{pmatrix}(\Sigma\Sigma^*)^{1/2}&0\\0&-(\Sigma^*\Sigma)^{1/2}\end{pmatrix},
$$
where
$$
 W=\begin{pmatrix}(\Sigma^*)^{1/2}&(\Sigma^*)^{-1/2}\\
\Sigma^{1/2}&-\Sigma^{-1/2}\end{pmatrix}.
$$
It remains to compute $W^{-1}$.

Comment: In this form we can get $B=\begin{bmatrix}
a&0
\\
0&b
\end{bmatrix}$ But in the problem the B is in the form $B=\begin{bmatrix}
0&a
\\
b&0
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I have corrected the answer. Sorry for possible misprints, not enough time to check.

Comment: How do you get the second row? Is this a trick or just by trial and error?

Comment: The eigenvalues of $\begin{pmatrix}0&\Sigma\\\Sigma&0\end{pmatrix}$ are those of $\begin{pmatrix}(\Sigma^*\Sigma)^{1/2}&0\\0&-(\Sigma^*\Sigma)^{1/2}\end{pmatrix}$ (this is easy to check by inspecting the characteristic polynomial, because $\Sigma$ is diagonal). In the one-dimensional case, it is also easy to find $W$ reducing our matrrix to this form. The general case follows readily.